# How to convert number inputted in any locale inside a UITextField into English number in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get some decimal number from the user inside a UITextfield in iOS Swift. Now the user can input number in his or her local number format as per the locale Settings in iOS. I want to convert this number which is in the user's mother tongue into English number. I searched a lot in this site (stackoverflow.com) and the majority of answers are for conversion from one locale (Chinese, or Arabic or Persian) into English but I want to convert number inputted into any locale format into English. How can I do this? So in nutshell, my question is whether the number being inputted in UITextField is in Hindi, Arabic, Persian, Chinese or whatsoever format as per the locale, I want to convert it into English Number format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `NumberFormatter` for that.

check below example:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
let localNumberInStr = "૨૩"
guard let str = numberFormatter.number(from: localNumberInStr) else {return}
print(str)  //"23"
```

Comment: Happy to help you.. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you check the devices locale you know which locale the user is using.

```
let locale = Locale.current
```

Comment: That much I know. Maybe I should rephrase my question. My question is whether the number is in Hindi, Arabic, Persian, Chinese or whatsoever format as per the locale, I want to convert it into English Number format.

Answer (score 0):

Just to improve upon Dharmesh answer, here is the answer wrapped in a helper method for use throughout the code. Obviously, it assumes that while getting user input via UITextField one has considered the number set in the user's locale settings.

```
func convertLocaleNumberIntoEnglish(localeNumberString: String?) -> String? {

    guard let ulocaleNumberString = localeNumberString else {return nil}
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    let localNumberInStr = ulocaleNumberString
    guard let number = numberFormatter.number(from: localNumberInStr) else {return nil}

    let str = String(format:"%f", number.doubleValue) 

    return str

}
```